# Trying to render ASCII art in python faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

I'm trying to build a text-based, open world game in python

```
world = [["=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","=","="],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
     [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
    ]

for i in world:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end="")
    print("")
```

This code successfully prints the world map, albeit somewhat slowly.  Is there a way to improve performance?  Eventually I'd like to have a huge map where the player can move, interact with enemies, NPCs, etc.  Is there any way that I can speed up the render to get better than .1 FPS?

I am in Python 3.7 IDLE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String are already read-only iterators in python.  So you can do something like

```
world = [
    "  X  ",
    " XXX ",
    " X   ",
    ]
for row in world:
    print(row)
```

But you should really try to minimize even more calls to `print`, which is *slow*.  Maybe you can use only one tripled-quoted string ?

```
world = """\
  X  
 XXX 
  X   """

print(world)
```

Which such a string you can access the `(i,j)` element by counting the number of characters before it.  There is `board_width + 1` characters per row (don't forget to count the newline character), and you have `j` rows before element `(i,j)`.  Plus, indexing at `0`, you have `i` elements on the same row as `(i,j)`, but to the left of `(i,j)`, so the `(i,j)` element is `world[(row_width + 1) * j + i]`.

If you want to keep you double array because it's *mutable*, consider merging it anyway into a single string before printing it.  For that use `map` to merge each rows in one call.

```
displayedWorld = "\n".join(map("".join, world))
```

*edit1*: You could a list comprehension like TrebuchetMS did, but it actually builds a list while in python3, map will create an iterator, which doesn't need to store all transformed rows before calling `"\n".map`, and rather compute that list of transformed rows on the fly, without storing them in a list.

*edit2*: For partial rendering of the world, just use a range selection of your list before building the string.  For instance, world[j1:j2] contains only the world rows from index `j1` (included) to index `j2` (excluded).  So if you want to display the rectangle spanning from `(i,j)` with dimensions `(w,h)`, do:

```
displayedWorld = "\n".join(map(lambda row: "".join(row[i:i+w]), world[j:j+h]))
```

This is using a new idiom, a lambda, which is simply a unnamed function.  The lambda `lambda row: "".join(row)` is equivalent to the method `"".join`.  Hence `lambda row: "".join(row[i:i+w])` is merging only cases from `i` to `i+w` in the row.  Note we also selected only rows from `j` to `j+h` in the world.

Comment: This could work if it was one world, but not if it's a large scrolling world.  I should have specified - only a portion of the world will ever be rendered.

Comment: And I concur with Felix, it's a job typically better suited for ncurses.  But if you're starting out programming, don't overcommit and just use the standard tools.

Comment: Was thinking something along these lines with the coordinates.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.join()` to quickly string together a list.

```
print('\n'.join([''.join(row) for row in world]))
```

On the IDLE, there's a lot of overhead with `print`. You may preferably want to compile your string before printing it to get the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/curses.html) if you're on linux / osx. Using the library, you can draw pixels individually instead of redrawing everying all the time.

When it comes to a huge map: Only draw the part of the map that's visible currently.